# error in prediction - Keras Functional API

Tags: python, neural-network, keras

I have trained this model:

```
from keras.layers import concatenate
from keras.layers import Input, Dense, Masking
from keras.models import Model

x_in = Input(shape=(5,), name='x_in')

s_in = Input(shape=(18,), name='s_in')

s_masked = Masking(0.0)(s_in)

z = concatenate([x_in,s_masked])

dense_1 = Dense(40, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='relu', name='dense_1')(z)
dense_2 = Dense(40, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='relu', name='dense_2')(dense_1)

output = Dense(1, kernel_initializer='normal', name = 'output')(dense_2)

model = Model(inputs=[x_in,s_in], outputs=output)

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss={'output':'mean_squared_error'})
model.fit({'x_in': x_training,'s_in':s_training},{'output':y_training},batch_size=30, epochs=10, validation_split=0.3, shuffle=True, callbacks=[plot_losses])
```

I want now to predict now. But due to the fact that I have multiple inputs, I didnt know how to use `model.predict()`.

When I try:

```
predictions = model.predict(x_testing, s_testing)
print predictions
```

I get this error:

> The model expects 2 input arrays, but only received one array. Found:
>   array with shape (1710, 5)

I don't understand it because I gave two arrays `x_testing` and `s_testing`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should feed your inputs as a *concatenated array*, as you have done when building your model (`inputs=[x_in,s_in]`):

```
predictions = model.predict([x_testing, s_testing])
```